# HashCodeBuilder in C++

Tags: java, c++, hashcode

If I want generate a hash for a given object in Java, the easiest way I know is to use the Apache Commons [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html):

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   int age;
   boolean smoker;
   ...

   public int hashCode() {
     // you pick a hard-coded, randomly chosen, non-zero, odd number
     // ideally different for each class
     return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37).
       append(name).
       append(age).
       append(smoker).
       toHashCode();
   }
 }
```

Is there anything similar in C++?

Answer (score 7):

Use [boost::hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html).

Comment: Thank you, Guru! That's exactlly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the [hashCode](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method does not return an identifier for an object. This is a common misconception. There is nothing to prevent 2 objects of the same class returning the same value. The hashCode is meant for hash table data structures, not for identifying objects. Those are 2 separate concepts.

Comment: yeah, I see. When two objects' value are equal, they should get same hashcode. And they may be two different object instance. 

If I want get an object id, maybe UUID is a choise?